# Should I use a Local Index in Couchbase?

Tags: indexing, couchbase

Global Secondary Indexes "[perform fast queries at a high throughput](https://docs.couchbase.com/server/5.5/indexes/indexing-overview.html)."

So, is there any advantage to using a Local Index?

Can we say this?

- GSIs are similar to  ordinary indexes as in RDBMSes, updated live on insertion and used for OLTP.
- Local Indexes are similar to Hadoop or ETL, and used for analytics.
- GSIs update faster.
- Local Indexes offer more complex indexing logic--built with arbitrary JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those points are true. Generally speaking, Local Indexes (or Views) are an older technology, and are on the way out. They are being replaced by N1QL, for OLTP applications, and Analytics, for more complex off-line queries.

Comment: Check this out https://blog.couchbase.com/comparing-couchbase-views-couchbase-n1ql-indexing/

Comment: @vsr Thank you, I read it, And it does talk about the difference. But the most important thing is Johan's statement "they are on the way  out."